# Programmatically change 'parent_id' of category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category

How can I programmatically change the value of 'parent_id' in Magento 2?

I tried so far:

```
$category = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($id);
$d["entity_id"] = $id;
$d["name"] = $name;
$d["store_id"] = 0;
$d["parent_id"] = 7;
$category->setData($d);
$category->setStoreId(0);
$category->save();
```

Everything is saved except parent_id

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `move` function in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category`.

```
/**
 * Move category
 *
 * @param  int $parentId new parent category id
 * @param  null|int $afterCategoryId category id after which we have put current category
 * @return $this
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
 */
public function move($parentId, $afterCategoryId)
```

So you have to use something like this: `$category->move($newParentId, null);`

Comment: Works like a charm for me.